# what are the difference between this two type of tables? ( # and @ )

Tags: sql-server

What are the difference between a **#myTable** and a **declare @myable table**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In a stored procedure, you often have
>   a need for storing a set of data
>   within the procedure, without
>   necessarily needing that data to
>   persist beyond the scope of the
>   procedure. If you actually need a
>   table structure, there are basically
>   four ways you can "store" this data:
>   local temporary tables (#table_name),
>   global temporary tables
>   (##table_name), permanent tables
>   (table_name), and table variables
>   (@table_name).

[Should I use a #temp table or a @table variable?](http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/should-i-use-a-temp-table-or-a-table-variable.html)

> Both local and global temporary tables
>   are physical tables within the tempdb
>   database, indexes can be created
>   .Because temp tables are physical
>   tables, you can also create a primary
>   key on them via the CREATE TABLE
>   command or via the ALTER TABLE
>   command. You can use the ALTER TABLE
>   command to add any defaults, new
>   columns, or constraints that you need
>   to within your code.
>
> Unlike local and global temporary
>   tables, table variables cannot have
>   indexes created on them. The exception
>   is that table variables can have a
>   primary key defined upon creation
>   using the DECLARE @variable TABLE
>   command. This will then create a
>   clustered or non-clustered index on
>   the table variable. The CREATE INDEX
>   command does not recognize table
>   variables. Therefore, the only index
>   available to you is the index that
>   accompanies the primary key and is
>   created upon table variable
>   declaration. Also transaction logs are not recorded for the table variables. Hence, they are out of scope of the transaction mechanism

Answer (score 1):

Please see:

- [TempDB:: Table variable vs local temporary table](http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2008/03/30/sql-server-table-variable-vs-local-temporary-table.aspx)
- [Table Variables In T-SQL](http://odetocode.com/articles/365.aspx)

It is often said that @table variables are kept in memory as opposed to tempdb; **this is not necessarily correct.**

Table variables do not have statistics, and this can affect performance in certain situations.

Comment: Temp tables behave the same way w.r.t. memory/disk. In memory where possible, persisted to disk if too large, DDL created in the TempDB database.

Answer (score 1):

Table variables are all well and good when dealing with relatively small datasets, but be aware that they do not scale well. In particular, a change in behaviour between SQL Server 2000 and SQL Server 2005 resulted in performance dropping through the floor with large datasets.

This was a particularly nasty gotcha for me on one particular occasion with a very complex stored procedure on SQL Server 2000. Research and testing indicated that using table variables was the more performant approach. However, following an upgrade to SQL Server 2008 performance degraded **considerably**. It took a while to cotton on to the use of table variables as the culprit because all the prior testing etc had ruled out temp tables as being any faster. However, due to this change between SQL Server versions, the opposite was now true and following a significant refactoring, what was taking well into double digit hours to complete started completing in a couple of minutes!

So be aware that there is no definitive answer as to which is best - you need to assess your circumstances, carry out your own testing, and make your decision based on your findings. And always re-evaluate following a server upgrade.

Read this article for more detailed information and sample timings - http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/per/temp_tables_vs_variables_p1.aspx

**Update:** On a separate note, be aware that there is also a third type of temporary table - ##xyz. These are global and visible to all SQL Server connections and not scoped to the current connection like regular temporary tables. They are only dropped when the final connection accessing it is closed.

Answer (score 0):

'#myTable is a temporary table and benefits from being able to have constraints and indexes etc and uses more resources.

@myTable is a table variable that you define as having one or more columns.  They use less resources and are scoped to the procedure you use them in.

In most cases where a temp table is used a table variable could be used instead which may offer performance benefits.

Answer (score 0):

The table `#tabel1` is a local temporary table stored in tempdb.
`##table1` is global temporary table stored in tempdb.

and `@table` is table variable.

Check the [link](http://sqlnerd.blogspot.com/2005/09/temp-tables-vs-table-variables.html) for their differences